# Convert PDO::FETCH_ASSOC array into indexed array

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I  have following code

```
 $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT Name,office FROM `table`");
 $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 print_r($rows);
```

Which prints the following

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [Name] => Suki Burks
        [office] => London
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [Name] => Thor Walton
        [office] => New York
    )
)
```

And I would like numeric indexed array, like this

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => Suki Burks
        [1] => London
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => Thor Walton
        [1] => New York
    )
)
```

I tried to find a PDO constant for this So that I could use it like this

```
$stmt->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_INEDXED)
```

But i think there is no inbuilt method in PDO to achieve this, but what would be the good method to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: As clearly stated in the [**manual**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php), you can use `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` to fetch associative and numeric, or just `PDO::FETCH_NUM` to fetch numeric only. Full list is available in [`PDOStatement::fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) as described in the first document linked.

Comment: Why not post as an answer @Qirel?

Comment: Why not indeed, @Marwelln :-)

Comment: @Qirel I had been searching this for 1 hour, I can't understand why I didn't find it, Thank you so much !!, It works !!

Comment: improve your googling then :D

Comment: *"I have following code... `("SELECT name,office FROM 'table'")`"* - I doubt that's your real code, since that's failing with the wrong identifier qualifiers.

Comment: Yeah,  This is not my real code, Thanks,  Let me correct it

Comment: `'table'` <<<< that is what I was talking about here; the quotes and @Qirel included that in the answer which needs to be corrected and on your question also. Edit: Ok, I see he corrected it now, using ticks.

Comment: ahh!, Got it, Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manual on [`fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) states about the first argument, `fetch_style`, as follows (emphasis mine)

> Controls the contents of the returned array **as documented in `PDOStatement::fetch()`**. Defaults to value of `PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE` (which defaults to `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`)

Which means that for the full list of constants available for different fetch-styles, you should look in the [`fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) documentation. This shows that for numeric indexed array, you should use `PDO::FETCH_NUM`, which is described as..

> `PDO::FETCH_NUM`: returns an array indexed by column number as returned in your result set, starting at column 0

The end result would look like this, all that was changes was the constant supplied as the argument to `fetchAll()`.

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT name,office FROM `table`"); // Singlequotes are for values, backticks for table/column-names
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
print_r($rows);
```

- [PHP.net on `fetchAll()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)
- [PHP.net on `fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Comment: I still can't find the  FETCH_NUM , where you found it ?
 http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: [Please see this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46379978/convert-pdofetch-assoc-array-into-indexed-array#comment79718470_46379978) that I left under the question.

Comment: I wrote it in the answer too, but you'll find the list of constants in the `fetch()` documentation, linked in the answer. They're the same for both fetch methods.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Happy to help :-) Like @Fred mentioned, those quotes aren't for tablenames - they're for stringvalues, but seems like it wasn't you actual query though.

Comment: @Qirel Yeah...... thing is, for future visitors who are new to all this, could have thought that it was proper syntax; always best to show *"The real thing"* ;-) Ooops.. did I just infringe on Coca-Cola's slogan? *lol!*

Comment: lol !, Thanks, guys you all are great, Helping people without any personal benefits, You saved my lot of time, Thanks again :)

Comment: @Fred Indeed! Quite honestly, I didn't look at the query, as it wasn't part of the question at hand. I'll admit, I usually do that, but was an oversight this time ;-) But thanks to your comment, I've edited it! (I'm actually drinking some Coca-Cola now, and it's not on either of the bottles, you'll be fine! ;-)) *cheers!*